# Compare dates in two columns by next min date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two date columns `Date1` and `Date2`. I want to create new columns:

- new column `NewDate1`: using first row from `Date1` `'1994-03-31 00:00:00'` to greater than that value in `Date2` and get next min value
- new column `NewDate2`: using first row from `Date2` `'1995-01-12 00:00:00'` to greater than that value in `Date1` and get next min value.

Sample data:

```
Date1                       Date2
---------------------       ---------------------
'1994-03-31 00:00:00'       '1995-01-12 00:00:00'
'1994-03-31 19:27:00'       '1995-04-13 00:00:00'
'1995-01-12 00:00:00'       '1995-04-13 09:29:00'
'1995-04-13 00:00:00'       '1997-01-12 09:59:00'
'1995-04-13 09:29:00'       '1999-07-19 00:00:00'
'2008-04-04 00:00:00'       '2009-08-06 00:00:00'
'2011-11-04 00:00:00'       '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
'2013-04-01 00:00:00'       NULL
```

I want like this:

```
NewDate1                    NewDate2
---------------------       ---------------------
'1994-03-31 00:00:00'       '1995-01-12 00:00:00'
'1995-01-12 00:00:00'       '1995-04-13 00:00:00'
'1995-04-13 00:00:00'       '1995-04-13 09:29:00'
'1995-04-13 09:29:00'       '1997-01-12 09:59:00'
'2008-04-04 00:00:00'       '2009-06-22 00:00:00'
'2011-11-04 00:00:00'       '2013-04-01 00:00:00'
'2013-04-01 00:00:00'       NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What new columns?  You seem to have lost a row though.

Comment: I would suggest looking into what LAG() and LEAD() do.

Comment: all you seem to have done there is copied Date1 to NewDate1 and deleted a row.  Please could you explain that, and/or post illustrative data.  Reading your explanation makes me think you want to do something that isn't being illustrated by the data you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you all the time periods between the 2 date fields.  Redirect into a table if this is what you're looking for.

```
;with AllDates as (
select Date1 as DateField from Table1
    union
    select Date2 as DateField from Table1
)
select d1.DateField, min( d2.DateField ) as NextDate
from AllDates d1
join AllDates d2
    on d1.DateField < d2.DateField
group by d1.DateField
union 
select max(DateField), null from AllDates
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your question? Are you saying you want insert the value of the Date1 and Date2 columns into the NewDate1 and NewDate2 columns?

If so, then:

```
INSERT INTO DESTINATION_TABLE(NewDate1, NewDate2)
SELECT Date1, Date2 FROM WHATEVER_TABLE
```

This should solve or maybe I misunderstand?